In dart does creating an isolate means using another thread?
Dart is a single-threaded language, and it offers isolates to do multi-threaded processing. I'm confused; does creating isolates mean that I'm really using another thread?

Have a looked at their documentation, specifically the part about isolates?

Yes, but it does not actually provide a response.

isolates provide a way to do concurrent processing, they're not exactly the same as threads in other languages. They're a unique feature of the Dart language that allows for efficient, concurrent execution of tasks without the need for traditional threads.
